# Meaning of "because he took himself right out of the line-up. He quit cold."

Tags: meaning, informal-language

Part of a movie script of King Creole. Can’t understand words in bold and a whole scene:

> My mother was killed in an accident three years ago. It might as well have gotten the old man, too, **because he took himself right out of the line-up. He quit cold.** He lost the drugstore he owned, he lost the house.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sounds like the death of the speaker's mother affected his father so hard, that it was almost as if the accident killed the father as well. The next two phrases sound like idioms for quitting/giving up on life/etc that come from possibly sports or other areas. I can't identify them exactly, but the gist of it is that the father gave up on living/became depressed/ill as a result of his wife's death.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *line-up* is baseball jargon which means the list of players who are going to be batters during the game. To take yourself out of the line-up literally means to withdraw from the game and not compete. Here's it's a metaphor for quitting life and not trying anymore.

To *quit cold* means to quit completely, all at once, not gradually. If you decide to quit smoking by simply never having another cigarette, that's quitting cold. Here, again, it's a metaphor for how he suddenly completely quit at life.

Answer (score 2):

It means the accident might as well have killed his father because his father basically quit living when his mother died.